# How to insert array data into json object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a languages array. I need to insert my array data into Json Objeatc within a function.
I am a new student and I tried to do this using map. But it only inserts one data of array into a JSON object. But I need to insert all off array data one by one. But I don't know the way to that.IF anyone can help me with that it's really mean to me. Thank you.

This is how  I need to be my JSON object:-

```js
"displayNameLocalization": {
  "en": "Fruits",
  "fr": "des fruits",
  "ja": "果物"
}
```

```js
const data = {
  displayNameLocalization : {},
};

const languages = ['En', 'Ta', 'Fr'];

function testFinalValue() {
  displayNameLocalization.map((item) => {
    data.displayName = item;
  });   
}
```

Comment: Please provide expected output

Comment: I update my post...Can you look agin

Comment: Please read [ask], where it says "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as a "JSON Object". You have an object. When you call `JSON.stringify` on that object, it becomes a string.

Comment: ... see also [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Could you provide more info or your code ? For example, provide the data structure you want to combine with the languages array.

Comment: I found A solution...Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are overwritten the same variable in each loop of map, because there will be one element in `data` with name `displayName` , so in each loop you are affecting w new value to the same element that's why you input has just one value affected.
Can you afford an example of the input and the output that you want to get so I can help you with the code.

Comment: I found A solution...Thank you for your answer.I change my JSON object into 3 attributes and set array value true the for loop.